# Normal subgroup of finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $385$ and $N$ a normal subgroup of order $7$. Prove that:

> (a) If $x\in G$ then $x^{7}\in N \Rightarrow x\in N$
> (b) if $g$ an element of $G$ then $g\in N \Leftrightarrow g^{62} \in N$.

Any help? I've only managed to prove that $x^{55}\in N $ $ \forall x\in G$.

Comment: All the statements are vacuously true as there is no finite group of order $365$ with a subgroup of order $7$

Comment: Sorry I meant 385 (typo). I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $x^7\in N$, i.e. $[x]^7=e$ in $G/N$. So the order of $[x]$ divides $7$. On the other hand it divides $|G/N|=5\cdot11$, hence $[x]=e$, i.e. $x\in N$. The second part about $g\in N$ iff $g^{62}\in N$ can be proven in the exact same way.